# How can i filter and echo data from multiple dropdown?

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm having dificulties in filtering and then echo data from multiple dropdown. Can someone help? Kinda lost here.

I want to filter from the database the data corresponding each dropdown...

I have the following html code:

```
<form name="campsite_search" action="index.php" method="get">
Shedding</br >
<select name="Shedding" class="input">
   <option value="all">All</option>
   <option value="Low">Low</option>
   <option value="Moderate">Moderate</option>
   <option value="High">High</option>
</select>
</br >Grooming requirements</br >
<select name="Grooming requirements" class="input">
   <option value="all">All</option>
   <option value="Low">Low</option>
   <option value="Moderate">Moderate</option>
   <option value="High">High</option>
</select>
</br >Exercise requirements</br >
<select name="Exercise requirements" class="input">
   <option value="all">All</option>
   <option value="Low">Low</option>
   <option value="Moderate">Moderate</option>
   <option value="High">High</option>
</select>
</br >Biddabilty</br >
<select name="Biddabilty" class="input">
   <option value="all">All</option>
   <option value="Low">Low</option>
   <option value="Moderate">Moderate</option>
   <option value="High">High</option>    
</select>
</br >Prey Drive</br >
<select name="Prey Drive" class="input">
   <option value="all">All</option>
   <option value="Low">Low</option>
   <option value="Moderate">Moderate</option>
   <option value="High">High</option>
</select>
</br >Barking/Vocal</br >
<select name="Barking/Vocal" class="input">
   <option value="all">All</option>
   <option value="Low">Low</option>
   <option value="Moderate">Moderate</option>
   <option value="High">High</option>
</select>
</br >Drive</br >
<select name="Drive" class="input">
   <option value="all">All</option>
   <option value="Low">Low</option>
   <option value="Moderate">Moderate</option>
   <option value="High">High</option>
</select>
```

And the following php:

```
<?php

        $Shedding = $db->escapeSimple($_GET['Shedding']);
        $Grooming = $db->escapeSimple($_GET['Grooming requirements']);
        $Exercise = $db->escapeSimple($_GET['Exercise requirements']);
        $Biddabilty = $db->escapeSimple($_GET['Biddabilty']);
        $Prey = $db->escapeSimple($_GET['Prey Drive']);
        $Barking = $db->escapeSimple($_GET['Barking/Vocal']);
        $Drive = $db->escapeSimple($_GET['Drive']);

        $filter = "";

        if($Shedding !== 'all'){                  
          $filter .= "Shedding ='".$Shedding."'";
        }

        if($Grooming !== 'all'){                  
          if(isset($Shedding)&&($Shedding !== 'all')){
              $filter .= " AND ";
          }
          $filter .= "Grooming <='".$Grooming."'";
        }

        if($Exercise !== 'all'){
          if(isset($Grooming)&&($Grooming !== 'all')||isset($Shedding)&&($Shedding !== 'all')){
              $filter .= " AND ";
          }                  
          $filter .= "Exercise <='".$Exercise."'";
        }

        if($Biddabilty !== 'all'){
          if(isset($Exercise)&&($Exercise !== 'all')||isset($Shedding)&&($Shedding !== 'all')||isset($Grooming)&&($Grooming !== 'all')){
              $filter .= " AND ";
          }                  
          $filter .= "Biddabilty LIKE '%".$Biddabilty."%'";
        }

        if($Prey !== 'all'){
          if(isset($Biddabilty)&&($Biddabilty !== 'all')||isset($Exercise)&&($Exercise !== 'all')||isset($Shedding)&&($Shedding !== 'all')||isset($Grooming)&&($Grooming !== 'all')){
              $filter .= " AND ";
          }                      
          $filter .= "Prey ='".$Prey."'";
        }

        if($Barking !== 'all'){
          if(isset($Prey)&&($Prey !== 'all')||isset($Biddabilty)&&($Biddabilty !== 'all')||isset($Exercise)&&($Exercise !== 'all')||isset($Shedding)&&($Shedding !== 'all')||isset($Grooming)&&($Grooming !== 'all')){
              $filter .= " AND ";
          }                      
          $filter .= "Barking ='".$Barking."'";
        }

        if($Drive !== 'all'){
          if(isset($Barking)&&($Barking !== 'all')||isset($Prey)&&($Prey !== 'all')||isset($Biddabilty)&&($Biddabilty !== 'all')||isset($Exercise)&&($Exercise !== 'all')||isset($Shedding)&&($Shedding !== 'all')||isset($Grooming)&&($Grooming !== 'all')){
              $filter .= " AND ";
          }                      
          $filter .= "Drive ='".$Drive."'";
        }



        //print_r($filter);
        $rs = $a->select($view,$filter,$order,$offset,$limit);
```

?>